# Firefox Web Developer Toolbar causes Quirky Behavior

Tags: jquery, firefox, web-developer-toolbar

I'm using Firefox 8 with the Web Developer(1.1.19) add-on and Firebug 1.8.4.

Ever since Firefox 6 or 7, it has started to act weird. For instance if I type into the URL field, it properly looks for matches within the URL history but while it does this the URL field where I am typing goes blank.

It has a similar behavior for filling out forms.  If I have two user accounts on a website and I start typing my email address it presents me with my two user names.  However it is very difficult to select one of them as the user account field will go empty on me.

Firefox only gets into this quirky mode about half of the time.  Restarting it often fixes it.

Is there a solution to this?

Is there an updated replacement for the Web Developer add-on?  I rely upon that for my work.

Comment: Today I started seeing a black line around 3-5 pixels tall, that scrolls down through Firefox.  It starts at the top of the screen and goes down to the bottom, flickering while it moves.

Comment: Both of these problems seems to be limited to when I run the browser on my secondary monitor. It works fine on the primary monitor. I haven't noticed any other program having issues on the secondary monitor.  I reinstalled Firefox from scratch and it still happens.

Comment: I'm using a Radeon 5570 with Catalyst 11.9 on Vista.  Running 1440x900 (primary monitor) and 1024x768 (secondary). Both at 60 Hz and 32 bit.

Comment: Looks like there is a problem with Catalyst and dual monitors: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CaKxrLv2occ

Answer (score 1):

I use Firefox 8, With Web Developer 1.1.19 and Firebug 1.8.4 and haven't experienced any of the issues that you mention.

Are you sure that this problem is caused by the Web Developer/Firebug addon? Perhaps the problem is being caused by another addon.

Perhaps try disabling any other addons you have enabled and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: I disabled my only other add-on (ad block plus).  And I disabled ALL my plugins.  Still have the problem.  Even the firefox menu is affected. I choose an item from the menu, it shows the list of options for 100ms and then the list disappears or sometimes it displays normally.